# Scrolling gets mistaken for Gesture

Tags: html, css, mobile, touch

On a mobile device (also reproducible with F12-Tools in Chrome), when one-finger-scrolling a `div` with `overflow: auto` into a direction that isn't scrollable (either because no scrollbar or because already at the end) and then sliding the finger into a direction that can be scrolled, nothing happens as if the element freezes.

This is especially annoying when you want to scroll vertically but the user isn't as "exact" and scrolls a little to the left and then down.

Interestingly enough: This doesn't happen if the page scrolls from the `<html>` element (eg. Wikipedia or Stackoverflow) only if the scrollbar comes from an inner DIV (eg. [MDN example, click on "overflow-auto"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow?retiredLocale=de))

I've tried various combinations with `scroll-behavior` and `-webkit-overflow-scrolling` but can't get it to work better.

Comment: I've never noticed this myself but you are correct that it happens. I would be wary of trying to change the default behavior of scrolling when it seems to be explicitly made to work that way.

Comment: This behaviour is particularly annoying in a PWA where I want it to feel as much as possible like a native app. Instead I get a lot of comments that the app "froze" when in fact it just didn't scroll because the user didn't move his finger exact enough.